# unable to type commands in terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, bashrc

I was install mpi and I have given the path for it in the .bashrc and I closed my terminal and after some time again I opened terminal it's showing following error in the very first line followed by my terminal prompt  and I was unable to type anything in my terminal

> prompt means it is not accepting my key strokes from keyborad
>
> bash: linux: No such file or directory ubuntu linux@terminal:~$

( here linux is my username )

For that I searched and I found one solution is that remove the things which I have updated to the .bashrc. After doing this again I opened the terminal now the error message is not coming but in the terminal prompt I am unable to type anything

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem by replacing your `.bashrc` file with the default `.bashrc` from the installation time. You can do this from Nautilus (the default file manager in Ubuntu). To do so:

1. Open Nautilus.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to switch Nautilus path bar to address bar.
3. Type `/etc/skel` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to go inside `/etc/skel` directory.
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to view hidden files.
5. Copy `.bashrc` file.
6. Go to your home directory.
7. Paste `.bashrc` file.
8. Restart your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

1. Rename your `.bashrc` so that it’s not capable of causing problems, then reboot.

   - If that works, fix your `.bashrc`.
2. Type <kbd>Enter</kbd>stty sane<kbd>Enter</kbd> to clear any tty-related problems.

   - If this works, fix your `.bash_aliases` or whatever.
3. Log on as another user.

   - If this works, fix your offending `.bash*` file.
4. Try another keyboard.

Good luck.